# How to run two django apps on same dev machine

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run two separate django apps that need to communicate with each other using a restfull api. In the real life there would be two separate machines but during development i'm running the two instances on different ports. Trying anyway ...

One app is running on `127.0.0.1:8000`, and the other on `127.0.0.1:9000`.
I've tried running both on localhost or `0.0.0.0` and all other combinations but I keep getting these weird errors.

```
407 Client Error: Proxy Authorization Required
```

or

```
500 Server Error: INKApi Error
```

which as far as i could find is an apache error, or `403 forbidden`

What is the correct way to test two apps on the same machine ?

Comment: I found this: https://gun.io/blog/how-to-install-multiple-django-sites-on-the-same-server/

Will that help you?

Answer (score 0):

There's no TRUE one. But you could try using nginx (althought this works with apache as well, using the appropiate syntax - what you should care about is the general idea). You could define two fake domains like domain1.dev and domain2.dev, and build appropiate entries:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.dev;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.dev;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    }
}
```

note, however, this setup is incomplete and you should understand how nginx works. althought the idea here is conceptual and you can do this with, also, apache. ALSO the domains must be correctly defined in /etc/hosts (or the windows equivalent) for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Luis, any way to use this solution with simple python httpServer ?

Comment: No, you can't. if you want to setup two instances together without making them differ the ports, you must use a layer like nginx or apache as proxy.

Comment: trust me: is not that hard to use. IMHO nginx is easier.

Comment: BTW the errors you're getting are weird. How do you get them? In particular the fist.

Comment: I'm sending post data from one django instance to another using the requests package. i've been playing around with POST/GET and different types of data to try and zero down on the problem. Cant say specifically how i got the first one. This whole thing seems unstable (The first time I ran the two servers the requests managed to pass ... ). I'll give your suggestion a go... Thanks.